# Keep selection on initial row after closing popup Dynpro

Tags: selection, abap, alv, dynpro

I'm working with dynpros and ALV-tables in my ABAP-Report. When I'm selecting an specific row, and clicking on an button for an specific event, an dynpro is beeing called. After closing the dynpro I want to select the same row as in the beginning. How can I set the property to select that specific row in abap?

Comment: How do you build ALV? By using SALV classes or some legacy way?

Comment: Do you open dynpro or popup? They are different entities. Give us the code, finally.

Comment: @Suncatcher I'm using both. I have an Dynpro to edit the whole row and and popup to add an value to an specific cell in the selected row.
I can't share the code because it is an business critical application. 
The ALV is created by an SAP function module.

Answer (score 0):

After the Dynpro is closed, the ALV Grid is displayed again.

You need to set the layout with the selected row in your layout and call the same function module you used previously.

Sample Algorithm:

1. Display ALV
2. Trigger Event
3. Display ALV